# Best Practice to Migrate Job Engine OpenEdge ABL to .NET

Tags: .net, migration, progress-4gl

What is the best way to migrate an old program to an other language without breaking the connection with the old engine?

1. Use an Assembly
2. XML-RPC
3. Restart from zero
4. Socket Connections
5. Other way?

We have like constraints : Price(15p)/Time(15p)/Quality(70 points), because the old engine is in production used by many customers. The newest architecture is based on RESTFul architectural style. Information: The software is an ERP(Enterprise Resource Planning).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Progress OpenEdge AppServer supports web services.

However, there are some limitations here:

**Licensing**

The use of AppServer technology requires you to have the right licenses for these. You can run the `showcfg` program and look for something like:

```
Product Name:  OE Application Svr
```

Might have another name in version 10.2B - Application Server or Transaction Server would be what you should look for.

**Technology**

Version 10.2B was released in 2009, so it's well overdue for an upgrade. If you are on a support plan those upgrades are free. If not: consider doing it anyway if this part of the system are to live on.

10.2B natively only supports SOAP-based web servies. If you use the WebSpeed technology you could develop some kind of REST-based web service in it. However that will require you to do some work and it would be a very "roll-your-own" solution.

Even without WebSpeed you could set up sockets etc and write a small http-server in Progress, I wouldn't recommend it though.

Versions 11.2 (11.4 is currently the latest version) and forward has native support for publishing REST-based web services.

Possibly you could upgrade only parts of the licenses. Running the DB in 10.2 and the appserver in 11.4 could work. Progress general policy is: "Client products to Server products with one Major version back are supported". Contact Progress and ask about this first though.

**To do**

Read up on AppServer technology and web services in Progress OpenEdge! If you already run AppServer it's quite easy to make web services out of your programs. If you don't all hope isn't lost: if the programs are well defined you could quite easily move the "API" to AppServer. If the system is badly structured it might be a problem - or rather more work - but I guess you knew that already?

**Links**
[10.2B Product Documentation Collection](https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1164.openedge-10-2b-product-documentation.aspx)

[10.2B Web Services documentation](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dvwsv/dvwsv.pdf)

[11.4 (latest version) Web Services documentation](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge114/pdfs/dvwsv/dvwsv.pdf)

[Knowledgebase entry about version connectivity](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P72253)

Comment: +1, thanks for your complete answer and I'm sorry to be late.

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 0):

Progress can talk REST.  Why not use that?

Comment: We want to quit Progress, because the OpenEdge ABL is too lag beside Java, C#, C++, and in France the Progress comunity  is too thin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally follow your chart/question and Jensd's answer is more than solid, but I just wanted to add: Progress also supports a proxy system to allow .NET (and Java) clients to RPC (sort of) logic running on their AppServer. You could obviously use this to be REST-aware.

We do tons of both (native proxies and Web Services), but personally, I prefer this (the Java proxy) approach over Web Services (basically because there are, at least arguably, fewer moving parts to worry about both coding-wise and setup-wise), but there's a lot to be said for and against both.

And of course there's always ODBC, in case you don't care about the Progress-based logic, and just want to get at the data. We also do lots of that, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to be late.

The problem is, we mixed some Progress versions and technology between customers because we can't enforce the newest version with an other license type for each customer is a special case with a customer manager.

The software blend **4GL**(Procedure & 4GL code) + **OpenEdge ABL 10.2B** with The 'Object'  + WebService (based on Rest style) on **OpenEdge ABL AppServer 11.2**.

Obviously it is a very bad idea to blend 3 versions with 3 different technologies but we can't restart from an blank page (my boss will not accept that case because the customers need update and maintenance on the oldest version, based on 4GL language. He doesn't want to develop another programme beside the oldest because he want to link the newest code 'Object Like' into the 4GL procedure, with that choice he can migrate slowly to the oriented object program ).

I'm really  locked and blocked.